# CScript Application Error - The instruction at <> referenced memory at 0xffffffff

Tags: memory

We have a an error message that is occurring occassionally in our system. The images is available here

**The instruction at "0x7c82f583" referenced memory at "0xffffffff". The memory could not be read. Click on OK to terminate the program.**

Any idea what is causing it and how to fix this. My server configuration is as follows -

Microsoft Windows 2003 Standard Edition Service Pack 1
3.16 GHz, 3.75 GB RAM

Do let me know if you need more details on this.

Any help, any help at all is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The error is down to an application trying to read the contents of the memory location 0xffffffff. This is -1 as a signed integer and it's one of the obvious mistakes programmers make. Trying to read memory location 0 is an even more common one!

The event log should tell you which program is was. Once you can identify the program contact their support people.

JR

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is a a third party software. We will get in touch with the vendor and see what they can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to a database at all?  Oracle, SQL etc

If so, these could be useful:

http://www.developerfusion.com/forum/thread/43674/

http://www.ureader.com/msg/1677427.aspx